# вывод массива после сортировки

Tags: c++, сортировка, вектор

```
vector<int> a;
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Допустим, если в векторе числа лежат числа `10 5 2`, то сортировка выдаст мне `2 5 10`. Как сделать так, чтобы он мне вывел `3 6 11` без изменения самих чисел в векторе? Если в цикле через `i+1` то тут как?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужен свой итератор или диапазон. Можно использовать [rangev3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
std::array<int, 3> array = {1, 5, 4};
ranges::sort(array);
auto range_view = ranges::view::transform(array, [](int i){return i + 1;});
std::copy(range_view.begin(), range_view.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

достаточно после сортировки добавить одну строку

```
 transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), [](int i) {return ++i;});
```

но если вы не хотите менять данные в векторе, то можно впихать в другую последовательность

```
vector<int> v(3);
transform(a.begin(), a.end(), v.begin(), [](int i) {return ++i;});
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

еще один вариант

```
struct incr {
    std::vector<int> v;
    incr(const std::vector<int>& res) : v(res) {}
    int operator ()() {
        static auto I = v.begin();
        *I += 1;
        return *I++;
    }
};
int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> a{2, 5, 7};
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::generate_n(ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "), 3, incr(a));
    return 0;
}
```

и так можно придумать много вариантов